# Refreshing a Web Part Without a Post back in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, javascript, ajax, postback

I have a list with many columns in SharePoint 2013, I used SharePoint designer 2013 for displaying items , I have tow web parts in a page that I created in SharePoint designer 2013, one web part displays one column from the list (master web part, display all items), and another web part displays another columns from the list (details, only display one item).
I created a connection between master and detail, when a user click on an item in a Master web part (this is a link) then Details web part displays the corresponding information.

But post back happened ,I'd like to refresh Details web part to display the corresponding information without reloading the entire page. How can refreshing a Details Web Part Without a Post back?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use SharePoint REST and datatables.net.

see link : 
http://summit7systems.com/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net/

Comment: This link is very good , Thanks for introducing this site to me, but I can't use this solution , because I can't use button and text-box ,In fact, I used 8 web parts in a page(SharePoint designer 2013 : display item form) and they have connection between each other like that I explained

Comment: It depends how much data you got. But is smells like a large amount of custom code. If you don't have that much info on the page. Why not just list everything out and use jQuery to hide / show elements. Then you don't need to refresh the page

Comment: One example could be http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I've designed a page similar to the images above, when user click on an item on left web-part,the corresponding information about that item display on right web-part. I want refreshing the corresponding web-part , without reloading the entire page.