# How to create connection between Web Parts?Wiki Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

How to create connection between two web parts? I want to show record related to base web part. I create 2 web parts **webPart1** and **webPart2**.

In **webpart1** I show all the record when user select any row that time I want to display the other data related to this selected row in my **webPart2**.
**WebPart1** is **List View WebPart**.

Comment: OOTB Webpart ? Custom?

Comment: WebPart1 is list view WebPart .

Comment: I think you can find the answer in [this old question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111267/refreshing-a-web-part-without-a-post-back-in-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: Ok Mark I trying this.

Comment: Hey this is not work for me is any other solution ?